# 'Canadian spelling' question; close as workplace specific?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

Shouldn't [Can I use Canadian spellings in an American workplace?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95481/can-i-use-canadian-spellings-in-an-american-workplace) be closed as a question *seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies*?

Subquestion: Is there any way I<sup>*</sup> can see a close vote history for a specific question? If it has been 'voted to close' and then other people disagreeing with that, I wouldn't mind leaving it open.

<sup>* FWIW, my rep is > 10000</sup>

Comment: "*Is there any way I can see a close vote history for a specific question?*" **Yes**, [with some effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275144). Basically grab the URL with the question ID, replace "questions" in the URL with "posts" and replace everything after the post ID with "/timeline". For the linked question that would be: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/95481/timeline. There is no rep requirement for this as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

That question looks more like "how do coworkers tend to react to this?" than "am I going to get in trouble with management/HR if I do this?" to me.  We have lots of questions about behavior in the workplace that could go either way.  I tend to err on the side of leaving them open, personally.  (I only skimmed this one quickly.)

If a question has been closed, those events occur in the post's edit history ([example](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/95735/revisions)).  So do reopen events.

You can see more history with the timeline.  The UI doesn't provide a link for this, but you can see the timeline of a post by editing the post's URL from

```
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95481/can-i-use-canadian-spellings-in-an-american-workplace
```

to

```
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/95481/timeline
```

(Replace "question" with "posts" and the title with "timeline".)

The timeline doesn't show votes, but it does show review tasks, including close and reopen reviews.  See, for example, [this timeline from a different question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/95739/timeline).  So in addition to actual closures and reopenings in the edit history, you can see reviews that didn't change the state of the question.

Comment: O wow, that timeline is a smart tool ;-)